# How to wait any thread in ThreadPool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

My app gets new tasks infinitely, I have created a class that will handle all these incoming tasks:

```
class Executor:
    pool: ThreadPool

    def __init__(self, pool_size: int):
        self.pool = ThreadPool(pool_size)

    def start(self):
        while True:
            self.refresh_args()
            self.pool.map(self.handler, self.args)
            self.pool.join()
```

This code is wrong, of course. The problem is that I don't need to wait for all tasks in the pool. The `Executor` must add a new task to pool as soon as at least one thread will finish work. It will be endless loop and all threads in the pool must be busy always.

How to implement this logic? Or maybe should I look for another way without using `ThreadPool`? How is it implemented in other software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a `multiprocessing.Queue`, passing the number of tasks as the max number of elements in the Queue.

When you put something in the queue, that thread keeps waiting until it is in the queue. At the same time, you can make your loop like

```python
while True:
    queue.get() # blocks if queue is empty
```

and put every element in a new Thread:

```python
class Executor:
    pool: ThreadPool

    def __init__(self, pool_size: int):
        self.elements = multiprocessing.Queue(pool_size)

    def start(self):
        while True:
            self.refresh_args()
            element = self.elements.get() # blocks if queue is empty
            # put element in new thread
            # when task is finished, put new element in queue
```